# Iterate over rows in pandas df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, rows

I have the df shown below:

```
           CX     CY   CS
97539   0.39896 0.7787  0
97540   0.39896 0.7787  0
97541   0.39896 0.7787  0
97542   0.39896 0.7787  0
97543   0.39896 0.7787  0
97544   0.39896 0.7787  0
97545   0.39896 0.7787  0
97546   0.39896 0.7787  0
97547   0.39896 0.7787  0
97548   0.39896 0.7787  0
97549   0.39896 0.7787  0
97550   0.39896 0.7787  0
97551   0.39896 0.7787  0
97552   0.39896 0.7787  0
97553   0.39896 0.7787  0
97554   0.39896 0.7787  0
97555   0.39896 0.7787  0
97556   0.39896 0.7787  0
97557   0.39896 0.7787  0
97558   0.39896 0.7787  0
97559   0.39896 0.7787  0
97560   0.39896 0.7787  0
97561   0.39896 0.7787  1
97562   0.39896 0.7787  0
97563   0.39896 0.7787  0
97564   0.39896 0.7787  0
97565   0.39896 0.7787  0
```

I want keep only the part of the df up to the point when the value on the 'CS' column becomes 1 and drop the remaining rows. So I want to have sth like this:

```
           CX     CY   CS
97539   0.39896 0.7787  0
97540   0.39896 0.7787  0
97541   0.39896 0.7787  0
97542   0.39896 0.7787  0
97543   0.39896 0.7787  0
97544   0.39896 0.7787  0
97545   0.39896 0.7787  0
97546   0.39896 0.7787  0
97547   0.39896 0.7787  0
97548   0.39896 0.7787  0
97549   0.39896 0.7787  0
97550   0.39896 0.7787  0
97551   0.39896 0.7787  0
97552   0.39896 0.7787  0
97553   0.39896 0.7787  0
97554   0.39896 0.7787  0
97555   0.39896 0.7787  0
97556   0.39896 0.7787  0
97557   0.39896 0.7787  0
97558   0.39896 0.7787  0
97559   0.39896 0.7787  0
97560   0.39896 0.7787  0
97561   0.39896 0.7787  1
```

Any ideas how to approach it? Note that the value of 1 can be at any line, so I can't just use .iloc(). Ideally, I would like to avoid itterows().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always at least one `1` is possible compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then get index of first `1` by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), last filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[: df['CS'].eq(1).idxmax()]
```

Solution working if also no `1` value - then return empty DataFrame:

```
m = df['CS'].eq(1)
df1 = df.loc[: m.idxmax()] if m.any() else pd.DataFrame()
```

Or use trick with [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), only is necessary change order 2 times:

```
df1 = df[df['CS'].iloc[::-1].eq(1).cummax().iloc[::-1]]
```